# Angular 6 and Semantic UI integration

Tags: angular, angular6, semantic-ui

I would like to integrate Semantic UI in my Angular 6 to use their very nice web controls.

I found an example the Angular official Ng-Book (pg. 32), I see that I should copy and paste some files from the book repo (src/app/vendor/, src/assets/images/ and src/styles.css). OK, it works, but this is specific example from a already-build app and I want understand very well how make it in general case.

So, I searched some general way to make it, not only with this example referred from the book code. And, in the official Semantic UI website, I have seen that Angular 6 specific integration tool is not yet developed; I found only a implementation very old, referred to Angular 1.x.

How can I correctly (manually) integrate the Semantic UI in my Angular 6 application and how can I recall in my code a couple of very simple customized control? It were enough also a very simple example, with for example a Semantic-UI text field or a Semantic-UI button. Have you a very simple tutorial link or step-by-step?

Comment: Nothing special, same as how you would integrate any other 3rd party libraries. `npm install` add to `angular.json` for javascript and css or import css it via `style.scss`.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your very fast reply. Can you please make me a little example? Sorry but I am not very expert in Angular... Thank!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Angular project :

`npm install semantic-ui --save`

*angular.json* file :

`{
  ...
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
  ],
  ...
}`

That's all !

EDIT : Now you can use Semantic UI CSS classes in your Angular project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfnnry

Comment: Thank you very much... I tried and imported correctly. What about the last step (integration in web page)? I searched a very simple exmaple (i.e., add a simple tab in my page) and tried this tutorial but it doesn't work.

https://codepen.io/Siyanda/pen/Xmmzbe

Can you please send me a very short example only to integrate something i.e. a button or a text box?